# print order with pdfprint.exe command line tool

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, pdf, printing

I'm using pdfprint.exe (http://www.verypdf.com/app/pdf-print-cmd/index.html) in a .NET application. I'm printing several pdf files and several copies of each file in a loop. The code looks like this, this method is called in a loop:

```
    private bool PrintFile(string file, string printer, short copies)
    {
        try
        {
            this.log.Debug("Send command to verypdf...");

            var info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = this.veryPdfExe,
                Arguments = string.Format(@"-printer ""{0}"" -printermargins -mergeprintjobs -copies {1} ""{2}""", printer, copies, file),
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            this.log.Debug(info.Arguments);

            var process = new Process { StartInfo = info };
            process.Start();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.log.Error(ex);
            throw new LabelMakerException("Failed to print file: " + file);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the files are not printed in the same order as they were sent to the printer. Is there a way to control this. I have not found any command line arguments. Is there a way to configure a printer to be synchronous? All ideas and tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) after started it.

If it doesn't work (verypdf shut itself down before the printer start printing), use a [Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx) command after starting the process. Try setting dinamically the timeout according to different situations (i.e. number of copies, first use of printer, size of file).